# How to create some custom box into a Typo3 web page?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am very new in Typo3 world (I came from Joomla and WordPress) and I have some doubts related a thing that has been requested by a customer that use Typo3 for its site

He ask me to create some colored boxes into a specific page. Each of these boxes simply must contain text or links.

How can I do this?

I am thinking that I can solve in the following way (but I have not idea if this is a GOOD solution):

1. In the backend I go in the **Page** section and I open the settings related to the page that I have to modify
2. Here I have 3 columns (Left, Normal, Right) and for example I add a NEW **Regular Text Element** into this central column
3. Now appear to me the wysiwyg editor, so I click on the **Toggle text mode** icon and I pass from the wysiwyg mode to the **pure HTML** editor's mode and now I will create some div tags (settings the CSS settings for the background color and the dimension) that rappresent my boxes (and into these div I put their textual contents).

Is it a possible solution or is it a bad solution?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You may either use the RTE typoscript config to add some new paragraph styles, which will make the boxes or use the `section_frame` field in tt_content, a field called "frame" in the backend when you edit a content record. Both solutions would just need some typoscript (which you will deal with very often in the TYPO3 world) and CSS code.

If you need some more structure in the backend, there is also an extension for that called [`multicolumn`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/multicolumn). If you just need "more" columns in the backend (in combination with backend layouts) to achieve different looks, this can also be done by adding some typoscript config. To give you a more precise recommendation, some sort of scribble or design screenshot of what you want would be nice.

Comment: Meanwhile, thank you for your answer but I have some doubt about what you are sayng to me (I am very new in Typo3). What do you mean when you speack about to "add some new paragraph style using the RTE typoscript config?" Do you mean what I have done? (using RTE editor in pure HTML mode and insert here the HTML\CSS code), or do you mean something else?

What is it the section_fram and what is this tt_content field? Do you have a link to some good documentation\tutorial about it? (So I will provide to study it before asking again) :-)

Tnx

Comment: LMGTFY: [paragraph styles](http://float-middle.blogspot.de/2009/07/custom-paragraph-classes-in-typo3-rte.html) and some [more examples](http://www.comsolit.com/blog/2010/07/eigene-styles-im-typo3-rte-verwenden/) and some code about [section_frame](http://maddesigns.de/rahmen-fuer-inhaltselemente-in-typo3-44-112.html). Although some posts are in German, I think the code will help you. And no, tinkering with the html source code in the rte is the worst solution I can think of. This is, what typoscript is thought for: configuration of TYPO3.

Comment: Ok, tnx. I don't exactly know what is TypoScript so I will start to read about it on the official documentation :-)